# How to parse a repeatable option with two arguments with Python’s argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-arguments

How can I get `argparse` to parse an option with two arguments, which might exist multiple times? Like this:

```
$ cmd --repo origin here --repo other there --repo upstream url3
```

And the parsed arguments should be accessible for example like this:

```
args.repo = [('origin', 'here'), ('other', 'there'), ('upstream', 'url3')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--repo', nargs=2, action='append')
parser.parse_args('--repo origin here --repo other there'.split())
```

Result:

```
Namespace(repo=[['origin', 'here'], ['other', 'there']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use append action.

From argparse documentation:

`append` - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times.

Example usage:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 2 --foo 3 4'.split())

Namespace(foo=[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']])
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

You might also want to take a look at docopt project, which is by me the best Python argument parser package:

- http://docopt.org
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt